# Know which tab is selected

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have ActionBar implemented with 4 tabs. Each tab loads a fragment. In each fragment, I have an imageView with a bluetooth logo, that when the bluetooth is being conected, this logo should blink. I have this method implemented on all the fragments this way:

```
public void makeBluetoothBlink() {
    btIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetooth_blink);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) btIcon.getDrawable();
    frameAnimation.start();
}
```

Now, in the activity, I have a listener for the bluetooth state, son when it is connecting, it should detect which fragment is visible. Other posibility would be to detect which tab is selected. Booth options should do the work.

My approach has been to define a tag for each fragment and then check which one is visible and call the method there to make the bluetooth logo blink. But it doesn't recognize the method from the fragment. So that's why I thought about detecting which tab is selected may be easier, but I'm not sure about it, and I don't know how to do it.

```
public void onConnecting() {
    //Call fragment blink method
    Fragment current_fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tab1);
    if (current_fragment.isVisible()) {
        current_fragment.makeBluetoothBlink();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Android Development docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#getSelectedTab%28%29)

```
public abstract ActionBar.Tab getSelectedTab ()

Added in API level 11
Returns the currently selected tab if in tabbed navigation mode and there is at least one tab present.

Returns
The currently selected tab or null
```